# No entries showing: Unknown error has occurred

Tags: entries, singles

I have recently uploaded our dev site to the live server so we can populate with correct assets and deploy once complete.

I've set all variables I can think of to reflect the new environment, but for some reason no entries are showing and 'Unknown error has occurred' is shown.

The site is now on a subdir of a domain whereas before it was at the root. Also we're now using a Craft personal license as for this site we don't need more.

Could anyone shine some light on what's happened please?!

Thanks in advance, 
Tom

Comment: Check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for the underlying error message and that should help you track down what's going on.

Comment: Hey @BradBell, thanks for your comment, I forgot to mention I had already looked in the logs and nothing was showing. I've just tried a fresh install and it's still not working, so I'm assuming perhaps some ownership or permissions problems?!

Comment: Open your browser's inspector and click on the network tab, then load that page.  You'll see one of the requests is an AJAX call to `getElements`. Click on that and see what the response coming back says.